# Global Data with UserDefaults - Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, nsuserdefaults, watchkit

I want to store a String permanently and access it on multiple Interface Controllers using global data. This is my code for setting the String when a button is pressed.

> All code below is on Interface Controller 1

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("yellow", forKey: "newBingoColor")
```

This code below is in Awake With Context:

```
    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    let newBingoColorObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "newBingoColor")

    if let newBingoColor = newBingoColorObject as? String {

        temporaryVars.newBingoColor = newBingoColor as! String

        print(newBingoColor)
        print(temporaryVars.newBingoColor)

    }
```

The problem is the string is saved to `temporaryVars.newBingoColor` and I can see it on Interface Controler 2 but when I restart the program, `temporaryVars.newBingoColor` is printed as nothing on Interface Controller 2. If I try to view it on Interface Controller 1 though it shows up fine?

What is incorrect here?

Comment: Show your code for Controller 2,  as is the problematic one

Comment: Are you setting your userdefault to empty while you do restart?

Comment: @ReinierMelian my code on Controller 2 is just `print(temporaryVars.newBingoColor)`

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Answer (score -1):

In you AppDelegate, add this line of code to the `applicationDidEnterBackground` function:

`UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()`

And also, add the same line after setting the key like this:

`UserDefaults.standard.set("yellow", forKey: "newBingoColor")`
`UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()`

Comment: synchronize() method is deprecated and will be removed

Comment: Can you post a source, the developer website doesn't say so.

Comment: Check the UserDefaults.syncronize() method declaration read the comments

Comment: Ah my bad, I see that now. While it's not deprecated yet, I am still going to use it because it will be a long time before it is unusable. That's why it wasn't on the documentation because it isn't deprecated yet, but it will be.